# What does a cdot/interpunct stand for in a (logical) set notation?

Tags: logic, notation

I'm studying Computation Tree Logic for a course at university. However, I seem to have forgotten an important detail about set builder notation that I haven't found online yet. I'm wondering if this is just a creative notation used by my university.

The formulas I encounter describe formal semantics of CTL in the form of:

$M ,s \models  p$ iff $p\;\epsilon \; L(s)$

However, some are more complex, including an interpunct:

$M ,s \models  AX f$ iff $\forall\pi\;\epsilon \; \Pi(M,s) \cdot M,\pi[1] \models f$

And below, which defines the set of execution paths for a Kripke structure:

$\Pi(M,s) \equiv $ { $\pi\;|\;\pi[0] = s \wedge\forall n \;\cdot (\pi[n], \pi[n+1])\;\epsilon\;R$ }

What does the $\cdot$ mean here?

Comment: Nothing. It says $M,s \vDash AXf$ holds iff "for every $\pi$ in $\Pi(M,s)$ we have that $M, \pi[1] \vDash f$ holds".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If it meant nothing then could it be omitted without changing the formula? Why aren't comma's used then?

Comment: It is not [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's another possibility. I'll update my question to include a case where set builder notation was used together with an interpunct. The examples I gave are indeed not written as such.

Comment: Oldish logic texts used notation where periods played a role similar to what we now do with parentheses. This seems to be a remnant.

Comment: It's separating the quantifier from the formula that is being quantified.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Using periods (or similar punctuation) in this way is very common in modern computer science / type theory. Using periods as a *general* way of indicating parenthesis is rare though. In fact, in many more formal contexts that use $\forall x.\varphi(x)$, it is not an alternative to $\forall x(\varphi x)$ as the latter is not valid syntax in those contexts.

Comment: @Derek Yes, some settings where type-theoretic considerations matter still use dot conventions. Nothing as extreme as in *Principia*, fortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the dot is just part of the author's notation for quantifiers:

$$ \forall x \in A \cdot \varphi(x) $$
means "the property $\varphi$ holds for all elements of the set $A$". The dot is just there to separate the $A$ from the $\varphi$ (since each of them can be multiple symbols long).

In $\forall n \cdot (\pi[n],\pi[n+1]\in R$ there is no $\in A$ part, but the dot is still there to separate the quantifier from the formula being quantified over.

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to understand the usage now looking at the other material. It was pretty evident, but my brain just gooped all over it.